# .slideDown (jQuery) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jQuery code to add html generated by a post in a div. The slidedown() function doesn't seem to be working right. Here is my script:

```
$(".expand").click(function(){
      var button = $(this);
      var id = $(this).attr("eid");
      var url = "/get-complete/" + id + '/';
      $.ajax({  
        type: "GET", 
        url: url,  
        success: function( data ) { 
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
          var lang = '';
          $.each(obj, function() {
            lang += this['html'] + "<br/>";
          });
          button.siblings('.comment-expand').slideDown('slow', function(){
            button.siblings('.comment-expand').html(lang);
          }); 
          button.attr('class', 'collapse');
          button.html('Collapse');
        }, 
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Here is the html:

```
<a class="expand" href="/#" eid="{{ event.id }}">Expand</a>

<div class="comment-expand"></div>
```

This is the sample data returned by the GET request:

```
[{"html": "\n    <div class=\"comment-count-bar\">\n</div>\n    "}]
```

This is the code to collapse the post, but this isn't working either:

```
$("body").delegate(".collapse", "click", function(){
          var button = $(this);
          button.siblings('.comment-expand').slideUp('slow');
          button.attr('class', 'expand');
          button.html('Expand');
          return false;
        });
```

Comment: At first set the `innerHTML` then call `slideDown()` (_if the element is hidden_).

Comment: `button.next` instead of `button.siblings` ?

Comment: @BlackSheep you mean like this: button.siblings('.comment-expand').innerHTML(lang);
              button.siblings('.comment-expand').slideDown('slow');

Comment: @BlackSheep The element is empty at first and is not hidden

Comment: Yes, but using `.html()` method, there is no `.innerHTML()` method. If the element is not hidden `slideDown()` doesn't do anything, hide the element using `.hide()` method before using `.slideDown()` and setting html content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET", 
    url: url,
    // setting the dataType to json, jQuery itself parses the response 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) {  
      // Hiding the element and setting it's innerHTML 
      // before calling slideDown()
      button.siblings('.comment-expand').hide().html(function() {
         // Mapping the response and concatenating `html` properties
         // If the response has only one array use:
         // return data[0].html + '<br>'; instead
         return $.map(data, function(v) {
             return v.html + '<br>';
         }).join('');
      }).slideDown(); 
      button.addClass('collapse')
            .removeClass('expand')
            .html('Collapse');
    }, 
});
```

Edit: Since you are adding the class dynamically you should delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.collapse', function() {
    // var button = $(this);
    // ...
});
```

Comment: i tried doing it using delegate. But, it instead is making the above GET again.

Comment: @Monique That's because events are bound to elements not to their className, when you remove the class the click handler is still bound to the element, one option is using event delegation or the `.one('click')` method.

Comment: okay i did it using one. Still not working. $( ".collapse" ).one( "click", function() {
         
          var button = $(this);
          button.siblings('.comment-expand').slideUp('slow');
          button.attr('class', 'expand');
          button.html('Expand');
          return false;
        });

Comment: I mean using `.one()` for the first click handler, `$('.expand').one('click')...`.

Comment: ok, so it worked. But, now there is another problem. When I click the expand again after a collapse, it doesn't work. So, should I put both in delegate?

Comment: @Monique Great, so I won't update the answer. You are welcome :)